# Equivalent definition of a uniform random $m$-subset of $\{1,...,n\}$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

Consider the sample space $M$ of all $m$-subsets of $\{1,...,n\}$, $|M| = \binom{n}{m}$. Let $Q$ be proposition that $S$ is a random variable drawn uniformly at random from $M$, ie. $S$ is any $m$-subset of $\{1,...,n\}$ with probability $\frac{1}{\binom{n}{m}}$.

for $x\in \{1,...,n\}$, let proposition $U:\quad P(x\in S) = \frac{m}{n}$

Does $U$ define $S$ the same way as $Q$ ? (ie. $Q\iff U$ ?)

If $U\implies Q$ is false, then what extra condition is need for this to hold ? ie. what is missing ?

**my attempt.**

I think $Q\implies U$ because if we define $S$ according to $Q$, then
$$
P(x\in S) = \frac{\binom{n-1}{m-1}}{\binom{n}{m}} = \frac{m}{n}
$$
but the converse ie. $U\implies Q$ is harder to show.

Also note that independence doesn't hold, for $x\neq y\in \{1,...,n\}$
$$
P(x\text{ and }y\in S) = \frac{\binom{n-2}{m-2}}{\binom{n}{m}} = \frac{(m-1)m}{(n-1)n}\neq P(x\in S)P(y\in S)
$$

Comment: $U$ does not even imply that $S$ is a subset of $m$ items, so the reverse implication seems false.

Comment: @Matteo I agree so I edited the question

Comment: "*What condition is needed for this to hold?*"  Frankly... as unsatisfying an answer as it is... the condition $Q$.  Even if you were to have specified that the sampling when taking two at a time were "fair" this would not have implied taking three at a time would be fair.  Specifying that taking three at a time were "fair" this would not have implied that taking four at a time would be fair, etc...  So then you would need to go all the way to specify that taking $m$ at a time is fair... but that is exactly the condition $Q$ to begin with.

Comment: $Q\iff (U\wedge Q)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that $Q\implies U$. However, $U\not{\!\!\!\!\!\implies} Q$. To prove this, it suffices to exhibit a counterexample.

Suppose you choose $S$ as follows; first you choose $s_0$ from $\{1,\dots,n\}$ uniformly at random. Then, you set
$$
S=\{s_0,s_0+1,s_0+2,\dots,s_0+m-1\}
$$
Here, the indices wrap around modulo $n$. For example, if $n=7$ and $m=5$, then when $s_0$ is chosen to be $6$, you would have $S=\{6,7,1,2,3\}$.

It is pretty obvious that property $U$ holds; for each $x$, we have $x\in S$ if and only if $s_0$ is in the range $\{x-m+1,x-m+2,\dots,x-1,x\}$, which occurs with probability $m/n$. However, property $Q$ clearly does not hold.

---

Your second question, "What extra condition is needed for this to holds?", is too vague for me to answer. I can think of no simple condition. In general, the marginals of a joint distribution are insufficient to recover the joint distribution. That is, knowing the property of each $x\in S$ tells you nothing about the joint probability that $x_1,\dots,x_m\in S$ for a list of $m$ distinct numbers.